# Чем являются «далёкое» и «неведомое» в предложении?

Tags: грамматика, синтаксический-разбор, части-речи, подлежащее

*С детства тянуло далекое и неведомое, всегда хотелось куда-то и на чем-нибудь уехать.*
Однородными...

Answer (score 1):

Правильное предложение, вообще-то, выглядит так:
*С детства тянуло **далекое** и **неведомое**, всегда хотелось куда-нибудь и на чем-нибудь уехать* ([Владимир Чивилихин. Память](https://www.rulit.me/books/pamyat-kniga-pervaya-read-4033-3.html)).

Однородными **подлежащими** являются эти слова в вашем предложении.
*Далекое* и *неведомое* — [субстантивированные](http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D1%83%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9) прилагательные (то есть в данном контексте являющиеся существительными): *тянуло* (что?) *далекое, неведомое.*

Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса РЯ:

**Неведомое**, как у Кафки, притворившись рутиной, **ворвалось** в привычную жизнь, изменив прежний мир навсегда (Игорь Сухих. Однажды была земля // «Звезда», 2002);
Голод освобождает их жизнь от необязательных жестов познания, с помощью которых **неведомое роднится** новым смыслом с повседневностью (Александр Иличевский. Перс);
Прошло несколько времени, и **далекое стало уходить**, становилось площе, теряло окраску (Василий Гроссман. Жизнь и судьба, часть 2).

[Субстантивы](http://www.tramvision.ru/words/subst.htm)